Godot Texture Import of PNG Results in Empty Canvas Instead of Compressed Texture
Problem
In Godot, when dragging a .png file into the inspector, it should normally create a CompressedTexture2D (like the play_button_h.png below). However, instead, an empty 0x0 Lum8 image is generated, resulting in the error: "Compressed texture file is corrupt (Bad header)."
Am I experiencing a bug, or more likely, am I importing the asset incorrectly?
Additional Information

I encountered an error saying: "Can't save empty texture as PNG."
When attempting to reload the texture from the context menu (refer to Figure 2), I receive the error: "Compressed texture file is corrupt (Bad Header)."
This happened with my background asset too. *Workaround was to make a new file & re-save png)
Running Mac OS Sonoma 14.2 | Godot 4.3 (no dotnet)
Project assets come from a reputable textbook

Figure References

Figure 1: Dragging a .png resource to the texture placeholder


Figure 2: Context menu for re-importing


Figure 3: Errors encountered while setting the texture



